# Video orientation issues when exporting with AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avfoundation

Here is the function I used to export video:

```
- (void) videoOutput
{
//1 - Early exit if there's no video file selected
if (!self.videoAsset) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Load a Video Asset First"
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

// 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

// 3 - Video track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration)
                    ofTrack:[[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

// 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration);

// 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {

    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
    isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
}
[videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:self.videoAsset.duration];

// 3.3 - Add instructions
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
}

mainCompositionInst.renderSize = naturalSize;
mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

// 4 - Get path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

// 5 - Create exporter
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                  presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
    });
}];
}
```

The problem is that the first time I use this function to export a portrait video, the variable **videoTransform (videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform)** are:

```
videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0
```

And the variable **isVideoAssetPortrait_** equals **YES**. Everything is right. However, after exporting completed and saved to Camera Roll, I used this function reload **the result video**. This time, the **videoTransform** changed:

```
videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0
```

And **isVideoAssetPortrait_** equals **NO**. It means that after one time export, the **videoTransform** has changed it's values (orientation from portrait -> landscape)

I googled many questions about video orientation of AV Foundation, but there hasn't found the solution yet.

Thank you for reading my long explanation. If you have any question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such concept as portrait/landscape regarding the video tracks. It has just it's   dimensions and a transformation applied in order to present it properly. By default the "portrait" video is encoded as it is produced by the camera (let say landscape) and a 90 degrees rotation used to present it properly.

When you export it, it's orientation is not changed, it is just recoded physically rotated, so no rotation is needed to present it properly.
This is why you get the identity matrix on the second time (it not means that it was changed from portrait to landscape), but this time the it's natural size is also swapped, and everything should be okay based on your code.

Please specify what's wrong in the later case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the later case, I also want to check videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform to set the renderSize of AVMutableVideoComposition properly.

Comment: And as you said the reason why I get the identity matrix on the second time, I wonder why the second time, the videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform is not same as the original videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform. Moreover, the exported video is scaled when I try uploading it to Instagram even though it plays well in the iPhone Photo app.

Comment: I think that it should work as you did code it, you were just confused by the change of the transformation matrix. Second time U have an identity matrix as transformation, so the presentation size is equal with the natural size, no change is needed.
Also you could use CGSizeApplyAffineTransform to get the presentation size instead of the conditionals:
    renderSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize, videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform)

Comment: Using CGSizeApplyAffineTransform the renderSize is right in the later case, but in the first case, renderSize equals negative value {-1080, 1920}

Comment: @WhiteMoney do you found any solution? I have the same problem with negative value. Thanks!

Comment: same problem did anyone found solution

Comment: if anyone still having this issue you can check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/71109215/9963757