# AVAssetExportSession rotation error's when video is from camera roll

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avassetexportsession

I am trying to convert .mov video to .mp4 and at the same time correcting the orientation.
The code I use below works great when recording a video using `UIImagePickerController` however if the video is selected from the camera roll I get this error and I don't see why:

> Export failed: Operation Stopped : Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11841 "Operation Stopped"
>   UserInfo=0x1815ca50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The video could not be composed.}

I have tried first saving the video to another file, but it made no difference.

Here is the code I am using to convert the video:

```
- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyAndFixRotationWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL handler:(void (^)(NSURL *outURL))handler
{
    if ([[inputURL pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"MOV"])
    {
        NSURL *outputURL = [inputURL URLByDeletingPathExtension];
        outputURL = [outputURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"mp4"];

        AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];

        AVAssetTrack *sourceVideoTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
        AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

        AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                                       ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack
                                        atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
        [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:sourceVideoTrack.preferredTransform];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                                       ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack
                                        atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [self getVideoComposition:avAsset];

        NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];
        if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality])
        {
            AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
            exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
            exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
            exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;
            [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

                switch ([exportSession status])
                {
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                        NSLog(@"Export failed: %@ : %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription], [exportSession error]);
                        handler(nil);

                        break;
                    case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:

                        NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                        handler(nil);

                        break;
                    default:

                        handler(outputURL);

                        break;

                }
            }];
        }

    } else {
        handler(inputURL);
    }
}

- (AVMutableVideoComposition *)getVideoComposition:(AVAsset *)asset
{
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    CGSize videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize;
    BOOL isPortrait_ = [self isVideoPortrait:asset];
    if(isPortrait_) {
//        NSLog(@"video is portrait ");
        videoSize = CGSizeMake(videoSize.height, videoSize.width);
    }
    composition.naturalSize     = videoSize;
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize;
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( 1 / videoTrack.nominalFrameRate, 600);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack;
    compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInst;
    layerInst = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    [layerInst setTransform:videoTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *inst = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    inst.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration);
    inst.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInst];
    videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:inst];
    return videoComposition;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AVFoundation Error Constant -11841 means that you have an invalid video composition.  See this link if you'd like more info on the error constants:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_ErrorConstants/Reference/reference.html

While no major errors pop out at me immediately, I can suggest the following ways to narrow down the source of your problem.

First, instead of passing `nil` for the `error` parameter in these calls:

```
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                                       ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack
                                        atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

create an `NSError` object and pass the reference to it like so:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                                       ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack
                                        atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
```

Examine the error to make sure your video and audio tracks get inserted in the composition track correctly.  The error should be `nil` if all goes well.

```
if(error)
    NSLog(@"Insertion error: %@", error);
```

You may also want to check your AVAsset's `composable` and `exportable`, and `hasProtectedContent` properties.  If these are not YES, YES, and NO, respectively, you may have a problem creating your new video file.

Occasionally I've seen an issue where creating a time range for an audio track does not like the 600 timescale when used in a composition with a video track.  You may want to create a new CMTime for the duration (avAsset.duration) in

```
CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
```

only for inserting the audio track.  In the new CMTime,use  a timescale of 44100 (or whatever the sample rate of the audio track is.)  The same goes for your `videoComposition.frameDuration`.  Depending on the `nominalFrameRate` of your video track, your time may not be represented correctly with 600 timescale.

Finally, there's a helpful tool provided by Apple to debug video compositions:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVCompositionDebugViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

It gives a visual representation of your composition and you can see where things don't look like they should.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. I still can't get it to work :(
`composable`, `exportable` & `hasProtectedContent` are4 all as you say. There are no error's returned from your first suggestion. I tried changing the audio track to use 44,100.
If I comment out `exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;` it works fine however the video isn't rotated. So the problem must be in there somewhere. Thanks

Comment: I notice that you create an `AVMutableComposition` in `-(AVMutableVideoComposition *)getVideoComposition`, and create `AVMutableCompositionTrack`s from that.  However, in `- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyAndFixRotationWithInputURL:handler:`
, you have a _different_ `AVMutableComposition` that you are passing to the `AVExportSession`.  Try passing this composition to getVideoComposition to create the AVMutableCompositionTracks from it so there's only one.

Comment: I just tried moving the `AVMutableVideoComposition` with `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` up into the main convert method so it only has 1 `AVMutableComposition` but still the same results. When selecting a video from the camera roll, it compresses it before passing it over, not sure if that's what makes a difference.

Comment: The compression should not make a difference if the asset is still exportable, etc. Did you remove the extra tracks?  You should only have two `AVMutableVideoCompositionTracks` in your videoComposition.  One for audio, and one for video.  You should create the `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` based on `sourceVideoTrack`, and try only setting the transform on the instruction.  Does the `AVCompositionDebugViewer` class show what you expect when you use it in your project?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I found this which works great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660250/video-orientation-issues-when-exporting-with-avmutablevideocomposition?rq=1 No idea why, but i'm happy with it. I will award you the bounty for all your help. My next step is to set a variable bitrate to keep the file size below a limit, if you have any pointers?

Comment: I appreciate it!  `AVAssetExportSession` gives you a limited number of presets that affect quality and file size.  You may want to look into  `AVAssetWriter` (and `AVAssetWriterInput`/ `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`) where you can specify average bit rate, etc.  Settings you may be able to use are listed in https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html under Video Settings

Comment: I fount that error will asset.during.timeScale == asset.videotrack.naturalTimeScale . Success with asset.during.timeScale == asset.audiotrack.naturalTimeScale

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use the method isValidForAsset:timeRange:validationDelegate: of AVVideoCompostion, it will diagnose any issue with your video composition.
I had the same problem and the solution for me was to create the layerInstruction with the AVMutableCompositionTrack instead of the original track:

```
layerInst = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack];
```

Comment: You sir are a champion. Was stuck on this for hours and this was the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting the below line and run your project

```
exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;
```

Comment: This will remove any transforms, crops etc added to the mutable video composition, so no use in this case.

Comment: This worked for me too. I'm curious why though. Does anyone know?